# App hangs on iPod Touch, but not iPhone

Tags: ios, freeze, ipod-touch, launch-screen

I've just released my first app. I have received an email from someone saying that on their iPod Touch the app hangs on start up (black screen).

I can't replicate this on either the simulator, or my iPhone 4s. Apparently it hangs and doesn't crash, so I don't expect a crash report.

- Both his iPod touch and my iPhone are running iOS 9.2 and the app is 8.3+
- I'm using a launch screen storyboard that appears to work on other devices
- The guy who reported this to me has made iOS apps himself before, so I assume he know's what he's doing

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this? I'm a bit stumped. I would love to ask a more specific question, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Send Apple a bug report. In addition, ask the user if he/she could send you the logs from the iPod after start up of your app. As he/she is a developer he/she should be able to do this.

Comment: @dasdom thanks for the reply. Don't the logs only log crashes, or is it other data too? (I don't know) He specifically said it is "hanging not crashing" so if it only logs crashes I'm thinking there may be no log.

Comment: The logs tell a lot more that crashes. Try it yourself. Attach your iPhone to your Mac and open Window / Devices in Xcode. Then expand the log if it is not expanded already.